# Selection of data from Yahoo search bar using csselector fails

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

```
package p111;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Yahoo_c {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver wi = new FirefoxDriver();
        wi.get("https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us");
        wi.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='UHSearchBox']")).sendKeys("pizza");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("wait ended");
        }
        String sl = wi.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id^='yui_3_12_0_1_14']")).getText();
        System.out.println(sl);
    }
}
```

---

Above is the code.
When i run this, execution goes until "pizza" being entered into yahoo search.Later with no error message in console execution terminates.
The error image is [image]
Please help resolve this issue.Am trying to select pizza delivery from list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Name instead of path as the yahoo search has a name for selenium to work with. Please let know if Xpath is must for you to work then i will change my code.

```
 public static void main(String [] arg){
        WebDriver wi = new FirefoxDriver();
        wi.get("https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us");


       WebElement yahooSearch= wi.findElement(By.name("p"));
        yahooSearch.sendKeys("pizza");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("wait ended");
        }
        String sl = wi.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id^='yui_3_12_0_1_14']")).getText();
        System.out.println(sl);


    }
}
```

Or you can use the same by ID

```
public static void main(String [] arg){
        WebDriver wi = new FirefoxDriver();
        wi.get("https://in.yahoo.com/?p=us");


       WebElement yahooSearch= wi.findElement(By.id("UHSearchBox"));
        yahooSearch.sendKeys("pizza");

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("wait ended");
        }
        String sl = wi.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id^='yui_3_12_0_1_14']")).getText();
        System.out.println(sl);


    }
```

Comment: Hi Asit, i need to type pizza in yahoo search bar.This would prompt a list of topics. Out of this topic i need to select 'pizza delivery'.Have used cssselector in code as am still a novice. Could you please code such that pizza delivery topic is selected for yahoo search bar.[Above code did not select pizza 'delivery' & did not throw any error-> execution terminated.

Answer (score 0):

The option you are trying to click is a `link` in `<a>` anchor tag.. you can simply use `By.linkText` if you are specific on the link.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("pizza delivery")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are sendKeys, even though the pizza is typed but the drop-down list does not appears **because sendKeys is not equivalent of typing through keyboard**. Work around is simple. You need to perform a keyboard action after writing "pizza".

```
// type pizza
wi.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='UHSearchBox']")).sendKeys("pizza");

// now perform keyboard action (of pressing space key)
wi.findElement(By.xpath("String")).SendKeys(Keys.Space);

// now click on the pizza delivery link
wi.findElement(By.linkText("pizza delivery")).click();
```

Try above code in your project, **after adding proper wait and with correct element locators.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath //*[contains(text(),'pizza delivery')]
It'll work! :)
Check this in firepath and make sure you get only one node with the locator.